# How closely must clues relate to the keywords?

Tags: decrypto

My friend and I got into quite a heated discussion about which words are allowed to be used as clues, the disagreement was in the interpretation of the rule (emphasis mine):

> **The Clues must refer to the meaning of the Keywords.** The Clues
> must never refer to the spelling (“C” to hint at “Cursed”), the number
> of letters(“8” or “8 letters” to hint at “Scorpion”), the position on
> the Screen (“musketeers” to hint at the word in the third position),
> or pronunciation (“face” to make your team guess “Place”).

[*Decrypto English Rules*](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/156950/english-rules)

I understood the part in bold to be in contrast to the rest of it, that the encryptor must be thinking of the meaning of the word, not the spelling, number of letters, position, or pronunciation. But the clue can be stretched as far as you like, and take multiple steps to guess the keyword, at the risk that your own teammates might not make the connection.

My friend understood it to mean that the clue must be closely related to the meaning of the word. That is, the clue is not allowed to refer to something else, which can then be related to the keyword. He said, in terms of 'relatedness', there is a sweet spot for clues. One where it is not too closely related to be too easy, yet not too far removed that it becomes illegal.

My main concern with that interpretation is that there is no objective way to evaluate whether a clue is legal.

My friend's objection to my interpretation is that it can make it impossible for the opponent to intercept the messages.

What is the intention of the quoted rule, namely the emphasised bit?

### Examples

- "Generally" as a clue for "Army"

My friend said "General" would have been fine. But since it's using a bit of wordplay to step from "Generally" to "General", it violates the spelling/pronunciation rule.

- "Sea" as a clue for "Army"

This is an example of multiple steps. "Sea" relates to "Navy", which relates to "Army". "Sea" and "Army" don't relate. I think that is legal, my friend thought the degree of separation is too far, since the clue does not *directly* refer to the meaning.

- "Default Skin" as a clue for "Job"

My teammate and I both enjoy Minecraft, in which the default skin is named "Steve", and "Steve Jobs" makes the connection to the keyword. I thought it was a brilliant (and legal) clue, but my friend argued that "Default Skin" does not refer to the meaning of "Job". Also, since the common "Steve" part is different in meaning in both cases, it's a bigger stretch.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find any official rulings, but here are my 2 cents.

Any clue you give as the Clue Giver that you can connect back to the keyword is valid. The end goal is for your team to correctly guess the code while keeping the opposing team from guessing your keywords. You do not need to justify your clues to the opposing team. If your team is also not getting the clues, you may need to rethink the wordplay and clue complexity.

Let's take a look at your examples:

- "Generally" as a clue for "Army"

I don't see this as a clue that breaks any rules.

> My friend said "General" would have been fine.

Both you and your friend are correct. Which clue is "better" depends on how well you know your team and the opposing team. I think that "Generally" is a better clue than "General" since it adds another level of vagueness. While "General" is also a good clue, this may be too obviously connected to Army, and it's not too far removed from "Generally".

- "Sea" as a clue for "Army"

Again, this is a valid clue. Depending on the other keywords available, it's hard to say if this is a "good" clue.

- "Default Skin" as a clue for "Job"

I think this clue will depend on the players. It's not a clue I would use when playing with a random group, but if I knew someone on my team would understand the reference, then it's something I would use.

---

I think all of these clues are valid. It's unclear if the "friend" is on your team or the opposing team, which may change this answer. The entire point of the game is using logic to relate a group of words to one specific keyword.

The further away a clue is from the keyword, the higher the chance of a Miscommunication. The closer a clue is to the keyword, the higher the chance of an Interception. It's up to the Clue Giver to find that sweet spot based on the players. This game has no tournament rules; it's meant to be light, loose, and fun.